# Why so many apache slots marked as "busy"?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, memory

During the month of May there was a spike in the amount of busy apache slots. What could have caused this spike?

If you look at Google Analytics (included below) there isn't really a change of traffic during May.

I also included the mysql graph to show that I enabled mysql caching at one point but I doubt it would cause more busy apache process.

**Question**

- What could have caused this busy server spike?

**Stats**

- Apache process: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jYnO.png
- Mysql: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fifr.png
- Google Analytics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTeMj.png

Comment: First, please increase kernel limit/tcp-ip stack for for server Then, put Apache behind reverse proxy (reverse proxy may be config for cachinh). In this case, you can try nginx like as reverse proxy with caching for performance. Absolutely optimize your apache config (disable module not use, edit parameter mpm, ....)

Comment: @tquang Thanks for the information. I'll research every term to learn more about it.

Comment: What do your access logs tell you?  Consider modifying the format to include response time.

Comment: I checked my access logs and there doesn't seem to be any increase to the amount of accesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics doesn't include traffic from web spiders, which is the likely source of your additional traffic.  I'd recommend that you checkout out your crawl statistics using Google's Webmaster Tools.  It (obviously) will only show you traffic generated by GoogleBot, but might offer a bit of insight.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Please check my note above in the comments.